# dovecot - Internal error occurred - failed to store into mailbox

Tags: dovecot

I have a problem that I don't know what's going on. I have an account that in the inbox has more than 100000 emails, I performed the re-indexing of the account, I made the copy of the emails and I already moved to another folder I deleted all the emails from the inbox and even so the emails no longer reach the inbox. my dovecot is configured dbbox is there any email limit per folder? the log doesn't show me anything. I'll post the log here for you to take a look at.

```
2022-04-28T12:11:15.985639620Z Apr 28 12:11:15 lmtp(publicacoes@atitudejur.com.br): Error: rename(/srv/dovecot2/mail/atitudejur.com.br/publicacoes/storage/.temp.1651147875.P99844Q1M867714.97c55cacfb0a, /srv/dovecot2/mail/atitudejur.com.br/publicacoes/storage/m.141313) failed: No space left on device
2022-04-28T12:11:15.986651832Z Apr 28 12:11:15 lmtp(publicacoes@atitudejur.com.br): Error: uOb6LmOEamIEhgEA5dpidw: sieve: msgid=unspecified: failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2022-04-28 12:11:15]
```

Comment: What does `df -i` say about available inodes? You're likely hitting inodes limit on the filesystem where your mailboxes are stored..

Comment: 150 / 5.000
Resultados de tradução
It is a network mounted folder with ceph mds, several accounts run on the same mount point if it were inode the other accounts would also stop receiving email



Filesystem                                                 Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
10.0.0.90:6789,10.0.0.92:6789,10.0.0.93:6789:/dovecot2/mail 25882426     -     -     - /srv/dovecot2/mail

Comment: Well, it seems that it is able to store a temporary file in the same directory, but fails to rename it with "no space left on device". To me it's a storage issue and I would be looking into storage backend quotas/limits and such, but I'm not a Ceph master..